# Bash script - For loop multiple arguments and awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, centos, yum

I'm trying to write a BASH script for patching my CentOS servers. My goal is that when I run the script, it outputs the package name, the currently installed version, and new package version. Something like this:

```
nspr.x86_64 / 4.8.8-3.el6 / 4.8.9-3.el6_2
```

This way, if I ever need to downgrade because a package broke something, I have a record of this.

The command `yum check-update` command gives me the 1st piece of information (the package name) and the 3rd piece of information (the new version) listed above, and I can use `awk` to separate the two. It's easy after that; just run `rpm -q {package}` to get the 2nd piece of information, then concatenate them.

However, I'm running into trouble with the `for` loop in my code. I need to pass multiple arguments into the loop (the package name and newer version) so I can `echo` them later.

Here's my code:

```
for package in `/usr/bin/yum --cacheonly --noplugins check-update | awk '{print $1, $2}'`;
do
    OLD_VER=`rpm -q ${package}` # ${package} should actually be $1 from the awk statement above

    NEW_VER=${2} # This is $2 from the awk statement above

    echo "${package} / ${OLD_VER} / ${NEW_VER}"
done
```

Pardon the obvious errors in the code; I'm new to BASH scripting. My confusion mostly stems from awk; I'm not very familiar with it, nor how it interacts with a BASH script. However, I think it's clear what I'm trying to do. Does `package` get passed as an array? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: one solution would be to do the whole thing in awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to read the whole line:

```
 /usr/bin/yum --cacheonly --noplugins check-update |
 while read line; do
   set - $line;
   echo first: $1 second: $2
 done
```

Comment: You should let `read` do the splitting; `yum ... | while read first second; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/usr/bin/yum --cacheonly --noplugins check-update \
    | awk '{package=$1; newVer=$2; cmd = "rpm -q " package; cmd | getline oldVer; close(cmd); print package " / " oldVer " / " newVer}'
```

The issue with your script was that although both bash and awk use `$` to reference variables, they are different vars and you can't reference awk's `$2` from bash or vice versa. Writing everything in either awk or bash should solve the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with my current script using `set` ? I just found this example: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html

If you look, Example 11-2 uses the set command to separate string inputs.

Comment: Yes, `set $(yum ... | awk ...)` quite simply. But a `while read` might be more elegant and readable.